# GAS: Having difficulty testing to see if activecell has a specific rangename

Tags: google-apps-script, named-ranges

I have a source cell with the range name "source".
I have some target (non-adjacent) cells with the range names "target1", "target2", "target3".

If the cell "source" is changed, I want the value of it to be copied into the 3 target cells.

I'm stumbling at the first hurdle in that I cannot work out how to test if I'm editing the "source" cell.

All the documentation seems to be about naming ranges rather than then working with them.

So far I have...

```
function onEdit()
{
   var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var range = ss.getActiveRange();
   var C = range.getColumnIndex();
   var a = sh.getActiveCell();

   if( range == "LXbar1" )
   {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('You are HERE!');
   }
}
```

revised code:

```
function onEdit(e)
{
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
   // Active range
   var eventRange = e.range;
   // Active range address
   var eventRangeA1 = eventRange.getSheet().getName() + "!" + eventRange.getA1Notation();
   // Comparison range name
   var sourceRange = ss.getRangeByName("rLXbar1");
   // Comparison range address
   var sourceRangeA1 = sourceRange.getSheet().getName() + "!" + sourceRange.getA1Notation();

   if (eventRangeA1 === sourceRangeA1)
   {
      // Target range name 
      var targetRange = ss.getRangeByName("rLamp08");
      targetRange.setValue(sourceRangeA1.value);
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `Active` elements in onEdit triggers, use the built in [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) it will ensure it will always use the actually selected cell when the edit happened.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var eventRange = e.range;
  var sourceRange = ss.getRangeByName("source");
  var eventRangeA1 = eventRange.getSheet().getName() + "!" + eventRange.getA1Notation();
  var sourceRangeA1 = sourceRange.getSheet().getName() + "!" + sourceRange.getA1Notation();

  if (eventRangeA1 === sourceRangeA1) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("You are HERE!");
  } 
};
```

Comment: Ah this is excellent, thank you. I THINK I understand it.

Going along the same lines I'm attempting to copy the value returned into the first of my 'target' cells. However the last line is doing nothing - not even returning an error! (revised code)

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `getFormula()` just returns a string. You can simply say `targetRange.setValue(e.value);`